# How to inspect network traffic from Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a third party chrome extension which sends some requests to a website and gets some data.
I want to analyse network traffic for those requests.
I tried using Chrome debugger, but that did not work.
Using tools like wireshark might work but that is a lengthy process.
Is there any chrome extension/other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Simply open devtools of the page that's making the requests. The popup has its own devtools accessible via right-click in the popup + inspect, the background page is accessible via chrome://extensions page (first enable the developer mode slider there).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can monitor an extension in Google Chrome by:

1. Going to Settings -> Selecting the *Extensions* Section. OR go to `chrome://extensions/` from the Address bar.
2. Checking the **Developer Mode** tick box in the **top right corner** of the page, which will change the display to look like this:[image]
3. Click on the link next to the extension’s `Inspect Views` text
4. A Developer Tools window will open up where you can monitor the extension by selecting the Network Tab at the top

Answer (score 1):

For extensions that do not have `Inspect views` in `chrome://extensions/`:

- Right click on the button for the extension (next to the browser's address bar) and select `Inspect popup`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see requests most probably because they are sent through a background service. Go to the Extensions Settings page and next to the extension you want to inspect, there should be something like `background.html`. Click on it, this is what you are looking for